# is there any solution for my react state problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

So I am a beginner in react. I was messing around with a to-do list and encountered a state related problem.

//main todolist

```
import React from 'react'
import './todolist.css'
import Itemtodo from './Itemtodo'





class Todolist extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
           todos: [
            {
                id:1,
                text: 'html',
                completed: true
            },
            {
                id:2,
                text: 'css',
                completed: true
            },
            {
                id:3,
                text: 'js',
                completed: false
            },
            {
                id:4,
                text: 'react',
                completed: false
            },
            {
                id:5,
                text: 'review',
                completed: false
            }
        ]
        }
    }
     // i think it came from this method
    ev = (id) =>{
        this.setState((prev) =>{
            const newarr = prev.todos.map((data) =>{
                if(data.id === id){
                    data.completed = !data.completed
                }

                return data
            })

            return {
                todos:newarr

            }

        })



    }
    render(){

    const array = this.state.todos.map(data => <Itemtodo key={data.id} todo={data.text} ic={data.completed} ev={this.ev} id={data.id}/>)

        return (
            <div className="todolist">
            {array}
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

export default Todolist
```

// item todo

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './itemtodo.css'


export class Itemtodo extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <div className ='itemtodo'>
           <input type='checkbox' checked={this.props.ic} onChange={() => this.props.ev(this.props.id)}/>
            <p>{this.props.todo}</p>   

            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Itemtodo
```

I REALLY think that the problem was from "main todolist" because if I changed the "ev" method to do "checked every checkbox with a click" like this, it worked

```
    // i think it came from this method
    ev = (id) =>{
        this.setState((prev) =>{
            const newarr = prev.todos.map((data) =>{

                data.completed = true

                return data
            })

            return {
                todos:newarr

            }
                     }) //set state ends
```

}

I did some experiment by console loging the "newar" and it did not change. So I think it's because of the

```
data.completed = !data.completed
```

did not work please help me! Thank you

Comment: You say you have a problem with the state, but you never actually say what that problem is. Is your problem that the checkboxes aren't always toggling when you call `ev`?

Comment: You should not mutate state try this instead: `const newarr = prev.todos.map((data) =>
          data.id === id
            ? { ...data, completed: !data.completed }
            : data
        );`

Comment: @ElanHamburger it's probably not a "state problem" i thought it is at first because the problem occurs when i'm learning `setState` but yes the problem it's just like what you mentioned the `ev` didn't do anything i'm certain the problem comes from `data.completed = !data.completed` because when i changed it to `data.completed = true` it works the way it should be.. can you tell what's wrong with my code sir?

Comment: @HMR thank you your code works great sir it's understandable....  i think i have the basic understanding of virtual DOM and and how `setState` works the way react compares the previous and the newer state.. i certainly don't think i mutate them directly since i'm returning a new array... your code works great and understandable and can you explain what did i do wrong i want to have a solid understanding and write better code next time..... again thank you <3

Comment: @Ihopemyenglishisgood You are mutating data with `data.completed = !data.completed` in my example I make a shallow copy of data: `{...data}` and toggle completed `{completed:!data.completed}` So a copy of data where completed is toggled looks like `{...data, completed:!data.completed}`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check this example. It is working fine.

**Todolist Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Todolist extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todos: [
                {id: 1, text: 'html', completed: true},
                {id: 2, text: 'css', completed: true},
                {id: 3, text: 'js', completed: false},
                {id: 4, text: 'react', completed: false},
                {id: 5, text: 'review', completed: false}
            ]
        }
    }

    // i think it came from this method
    ev = (id, changedValue) => {
        this.setState((prev) => {
            let item = prev.todos.filter((data) => data.id === id)[0];
            item.completed = changedValue;
            return{
                todos: prev.todos
            };
        })
    };

    render() {

        const array = this.state.todos.map(data => <Itemtodo key={data.id} todo={data.text} ic={data.completed}
                                                             ev={this.ev} id={data.id}/>);
        return (
            <div className="todolist">
                {array}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todolist
```

**Itemtodo Component**

```
class Itemtodo extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='itemtodo'>
                <input type='checkbox' checked={this.props.ic} onChange={() => this.props.ev(this.props.id, !this.props.ic)}/>
                {this.props.todo}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i can understand it.. so the difference in this code is that you changed the `completed` outside/before the `ev` is that where i'm wrong? can you pointed the wrong part in my code.. thank you sir <3

Comment: Still mutates todo item. If OP uses pure components or is going to optimise to use pure components then it won't work, todo item is still same between renders (has same reference) so React won't re render it.

Comment: Please check my answer on why you should not mutate state, it doesn't matter if you mutate redux state or react state because they can both break. If Itemtodo would inherit from PureComponent then your code will break.

Comment: @Ihopemyenglishisgood, render was executed two times and as you were set `data.completed = !data.completed `  so first render it sets true and then in second render it sets false. That's why UI did not have any reflection of changes. That's why I passed changedValue as param and set it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of a todo list that has TodoItem as a pure component, because toggleCompleted will not mutate this will work (you have to click on the todo to toggle completed).

```js
//using React.memo will make TodoItem a pure
//  component and won't re render if props didn't change
const TodoItem = React.memo(function TodoItem({
  todo: { id, name, completed },
  toggleCompleted,
}) {
  const r = React.useRef(0);
  r.current++;
  return (
    <li
      onClick={toggleCompleted(id)}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
    >
      rendered:{r.current}, {name}, completed:
      {completed.toString()}
    </li>
  );
});
function TodoList({ todos, toggleCompleted }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <TodoItem
          key={todo.id}
          todo={todo}
          toggleCompleted={toggleCompleted}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: '1', completed: false },
    { id: 2, name: '2', completed: false },
  ]);
  //use callback so the handler never changes
  const toggleCompleted = React.useCallback(
    (id) => () =>
      setTodos((todos) =>
        //map todos into a new array of todos
        todos.map(
          (todo) =>
            todo.id === id
              ? //shallow copy todo and toggle completed
                { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }
              : todo //just return the todo
        )
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <TodoList
      todos={todos}
      toggleCompleted={toggleCompleted}
    />
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

And here is a broken example where I will mutate the todo, even though you changed the data you did not change the reference of the todo item so React won't re render pure TodoItem component.

```js
//using React.memo will make TodoItem a pure
//  component and won't re render if props didn't change
const TodoItem = React.memo(function TodoItem({
  todo: { id, name, completed },
  toggleCompleted,
}) {
  const r = React.useRef(0);
  r.current++;
  return (
    <li
      onClick={toggleCompleted(id)}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
    >
      rendered:{r.current}, {name}, completed:
      {completed.toString()}
    </li>
  );
});
function TodoList({ todos, toggleCompleted }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <TodoItem
          key={todo.id}
          todo={todo}
          toggleCompleted={toggleCompleted}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: '1', completed: false },
    { id: 2, name: '2', completed: false },
  ]);
  //use callback so the handler never changes
  const toggleCompleted = React.useCallback(
    (id) => () =>
      setTodos((todos) =>
        //map todos into a new array of todos
        todos.map((todo) => {
          if (todo.id === id) {
            todo.completed = !todo.completed;
            console.log('changed todo:', todo);
          }
          //it is always returning the same todo that it
          //  got passed into, only mutates the one that
          //  needs to be toggled but that todo is still the
          //  same
          return todo;
        })
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <TodoList
      todos={todos}
      toggleCompleted={toggleCompleted}
    />
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```